# Android ActionBar is overlaying with the StatusBar in my application

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar

In my application, ActionBar is overlaying with Status bar, but I want to display both Status bar and ActionBar without overlay in my whole application.

But I am not setting any overlay values for ActionBar like `WindowManager` / `android:windowActionBarOverlay`.

I want to remove the overlay in my whole application and not in a single activity.

I am using `android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` in my application theme.

Comment: Use `@android:style/Theme.Holo` instead.

Comment: Glenn, Thanks but its not working for me.

Comment: If Iam using FLAG_FULL_SCREEN for WindowManager, it is showing full screen mode. But if Iam using FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULL_SCREEN, it is showing like my ActionBar is overlapping with the StatusBar

Comment: This problem is with only Samsung Galaxy 4